# Facebook Connect with django-facebook Test error?

Tags: python, django, facebook

i've followed all the steps in the documentation [here](http://django-facebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) but i didn't update my models yet and tried to test the log in on local host and when i tried to connect using facebook using the url defined facebook/login to test a pop up window with facebook with this error appeared "An error occurred. Please try later" Why is that ?

Comment: We need more details - check your logs or debug further until you can give a bit more detail into what's happening. We're not psychic

Comment: i want more details but i can't find any more errors in anything the only thing appears to me is the facebook error page only ,i don't know if the problem is that i am testing from localhost or what !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after searching the web a lot i figured out a solution and wrote a tutorial about [here](http://fadykamal.com/2012/05/09/how-to-test-facebook-login-on-localhost-with-django/)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have to set up application domain and website URL in Facebook application settings. They are empty or incorrect.

Comment: the app domain i tried to set it to http://127.0.0.1:8000 but it didn't work ,i am pretty sure now that the problem is that i am using local host but i don't know how to solve it

Comment: edit your host file to have something like www.fadydev.com point to 127.0.0.1. then go on Facebook & set the domain name to www.fadydev.com:8000.